# cakephp 2.x custom query pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

i have a cakephp function in my model that calls a stored procedure that returns a resultset, how do i paginate the resultset in my controller?
here is the function in my model

```
public function GetSummary(){
     $sql="CALL main_report()";
     return $this->query($sql);
  }
```

and this is how am accessing the data in my controller

```
$usagesummary=$this->Book->GetSummary();
```

how do i paginate this data?

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself this question: Can the store procedure be done with core Cake model? if yes, you better do it that way.

If not, then you will need to implement a custom paginator, that means you will have to implement the paginate() and paginateCount() methods on your model

Another thing you can do is to create a custom find type as [described here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types). If you take this path, and let's say you named your custom find "summary", then you will paginate this way

```
public $paginate = array(
    'findType' => 'summary'
);
```

What I said is just [a small summary of what you can find in the official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination)